# BSOD Driver_Power_State_Failure minidump

Tags: windows-10, bsod, debug, minidumps

Every so often I get BSODs due to Driver Power State Failure. I've tried the conventional wisdom of reinstalling corrupt drivers in Safe Mode w/ Networking, but to no avail. I saved a minidump of the most recent crash, but I had problems trying to analyze it in WinDBG (something about incorrect symbol paths... at that point it was too technical for me to comprehend). Could someone please analyze [this minidump](http://www.mediafire.com/file/hei1cekfa75h5dt/083118-8328-01.dmp/file) and advise how to prevent future BSODs?
Many thanks

Running Windows 10 Home 1803 (build 17134) on Asus Q302LA, SMBIOS version 2.7

Answer (score 0):

The most likely suspect (according to the minidump) is the driver for the Intel wireless adapter, Netwbw02.sys . It is also possible that there is a problem with the wireless adapter hardware.

If you can't find an updated driver from your machine's manufacturer, try here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005634/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html